# What tools can i use to write a java script for facebook console panel

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've seen java scripts've been used to do facebook tasks fast(by adding them through browser console panel) ,such as adding friends, sending messages, posting on groups....

```
 ie: $$javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _56bs _56bt');  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {  inputs[i].click();}
```

(this's been used to cancel sent requests..)
i need to know what are the tools/ides have been used to write these scripts..

Comment: why would anyone do something "private" as adding a friend or sending a message with some script? or posting in a group...i mean, you open the group, you write a message, you post the message...how would a script help you with that?

Answer (score 1):

To write Javascript, any editor would work. You could use something like VSCode or even Notepad.